# Using Domain Events to Update Entity in Database

Tags: c#, events, repository, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have a PurchaseOrder aggregate root which has Two methods FinalizeOrder and CancellOrder, they both record events: OrderFinaziled and OrderCancelled. I am stuck on modeling order repository, can i use those events inside repository pattern to update entity in database? i don't wont after each change to save whole aggregate root, i want to save only the field that was changed, i am using SqlClient, no ORMs.

my Aggregate root base class:

```
public class AggregateRootBase<TID> : EntityBase<TID>
{
    public AggregateRootBase(TID id) : base(id)
    {
    }

    private readonly List<IDomainEvent> recordedEvents = new List<IDomainEvent>();

    public IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> GetEvents()
    {
        return recordedEvents;
    }
    public void MarkEventsAsProcessed()
    {
        recordedEvents.Clear();
    }

    protected void RecordEvent(IDomainEvent @event)
    {
        recordedEvents.Add(@event);
    }
}
```

PurchaseOrder class (skipped most properties):

```
public class PurchaseOrder : AggregateRootBase<int>
{
   public PurchaseOrder(int id) : base(id)
   {
      IsFinalized = false;
      IsCancelled = false;
   }
   public bool IsFinalized { get; set; }
   public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }

   public void FinalizeOrder()
   {
      IsFinalized = true;
      RecordEvent(new OrderFinalized(Id,IsFinalized));
   }
   public void CancellOrder()
   {
      IsCancelled = true;
      RecordEvent(new OrderCancelled(Id,IsCancelled));
   }
}
```

and repository:

```
public class PurchaseOrderRepository 
{
   void Save(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
   {
      var events = purchaseOrder.GetEvents();
      foreach (var evt in events)
      {
         if(evt.GetType() == typeof(OrderFinalized))
            // use event args and update field using SqlCommand
         else if (evt.GetType() == typeof(OrderCancelled))
            // use event args and Update field Using SqlCommand
      }
   }
}
```

i also have an EventDispatcher which dispatches events (Email Notification) after AggregateRoot successful persistence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use domain events to save your changes, you are talking about *projecting* events to your aggregate state. There are some tools that can help with that. What you are trying to do resembles the pattern matching, a usual feature of most functional languages. To make life easier you might want to check something like [Projac](https://github.com/yreynhout/Projac). We use it for projections and it works very nicely. It also has [SQL Server specific implementation](https://github.com/yreynhout/Projac/blob/master/Sql.md).

One example that you can find there:

```
public class PortfolioProjection : SqlProjection
{
  public PortfolioProjection()
  {
    When<PortfolioAdded>(@event =>
      TSql.NonQueryStatement(
        "INSERT INTO [Portfolio] (Id, Name) VALUES (@P1, @P2)",
        new { P1 = TSql.Int(@event.Id), P2 = TSql.NVarChar(@event.Name, 40) }
    ));

    When<PortfolioRemoved>(@event =>
      TSql.NonQueryStatement(
        "DELETE FROM [Portfolio] WHERE Id = @P1",
        new { P1 = TSql.Int(@event.Id) }
    ));

    When<PortfolioRenamed>(@event =>
      TSql.NonQueryStatement(
        "UPDATE [Portfolio] SET Name = @P2 WHERE Id = @P1",
        new { P1 = TSql.Int(@event.Id), P2 = TSql.NVarChar(@event.Name, 40) }
    ));
  }
}
```

Then you can initialise projector instance:

```
_projector = new SqlProjector(
   Resolve.WhenEqualToHandlerMessageType(new PortfolioProjection()),
   new TransactionalSqlCommandExecutor(
     new ConnectionStringSettings(
       "projac",
        @"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=ProjacUsage;Integrated Security=SSPI;",
        "System.Data.SqlClient"),
      IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted));
```

And then project events:

```
void Save(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder) =>
    _projector.Project(purchaseOrder.GetEvents());
```

You might also check the event sourcing pattern although it adds quite lot of complexity.

Comment: it looks interesting, thanks, i will take a look at it.

Comment: one question about event sourcing and projections, do i understand correctly that if i have event store and when i reconstitute domain model from event it is projection, and also when i use event to update aggregate state in database it is called projection, i am new to DDD and CQRS and if i misunderstood something if its not hard can you clear it up?

Comment: You don't have to use event sourcing to use Projac. You just execute projections for your events.

Comment: I added some more code but you can better look at the repository, there are plenty of samples there.

Comment: Thank you, yes i am reviewing it ;) from your experience are there better practices for persisting aggregate root changes without using ORM frameworks?

Comment: The answer is always "it depends". I personally prefer using document databases, especially in the early stage when my classes change often. Schema changes are painful. ORM can save you some time but you must know what you are doing to avoid common issues with impedance mismatch.

Comment: Thanks you for your time.